# How can I prove a polynomial to be primitive?

Tags: field-theory

From what I understood is that one check I can do to see if a polynomial is primitive is taking the GCD of all coefficients and checking it's equal to one.

I was looking at $x^{4}+x^{2}+1$ and i noticed that it can in fact be reduced to
$(x^{2} - x + 1)(x^{2}+ x + 1)$ and all primitive polynomials are supposedly irreducible.
Is GCD rule just used to detect if something is not primitive but no prove primitivity?

Comment: See the different wikipedia articles about 'primitive polynomial' in ring theory vs in field theory.

Comment: @Berci But even in the article where primitive seems not to mean necessarily irreducible it is not clearly formulated that it is meant this way. At least I did not find the formulation " a primitive polynomial need not be irreducible " there.

Answer (score 2):

There are not enough words in the English language to describe all the concepts in Mathematics, so sometimes a word gets used in two different contexts to mean two different things. In some contexts, the word *primitive* is used to mean a polynomial whose coefficients are relatively prime. In other contexts the word *primitive* is used to mean a polynomial a root of which generates a field under discussion. A polynomial that is primitive in the second sense must be irreducible. A polynomial that is primitive in the first sense may or may not be irreducible.

If you think that's bad, just wait until you find out how many meanings *normal* has.

Comment: So the method I used is for another primitive polynomial definition ?

Comment: If you have a source that says primitive polynomials are irreducible, and another source that says that a polynomial is primitive if its coefficients are relatively prime, then, yes, you are dealing with two different definitions (in two different contexts) of the same phrase. Either that, or one of your sources is just plain wrong.